# How to Export several rows to csv file

Tags: powershell

How can I export several rows to a CSV? I have no input-file, I get an Array of info from Microsoft Identity Manager 2016. My code is below:

```
$output = @()
Foreach (//...
{
    $row = New-Object PSObject -Propert @{DisplayName = $ex1; PhoneNbr = $ex2;}
    $output += $row
}

Export-Csv -InputObject $output -Path $filePath
```

This code only writes the Array information. i.e Count, Length, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the advantages of Powershell

```
$Result = Foreach (//...){
    New-Object PSObject -Propert @{DisplayName = $ex1; PhoneNbr = $ex2;}
} 

$result | Export-Csv -InputObject $output -Path $filePath
```

Answer (score 2):

`Export-Csv` exports properties. The object `$output` above has the properties Count, Length etc.

This will get you what you're after.

```
Foreach (//...
    [array]$output += [pscustomobject]@{
        DisplayName = $ex
        PhoneNbr = $ex2
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation
```